# Power Supply Stacking in Parallel

Tags: power-supply, power, parallel, stack

I have two DLM 60-10 Sorenson bench power suppllies (10A limit) that I am wanting to stack in parallel so that I can provide between 1 and 20 A, at a consistent 12 V. I'm not particularly an electrically-savvy person so I am wondering the best way to go about this. It seems to me that the each power supply won't know that the other unit exists -- so since they will always be operating at the same power settings, is it as simple as splicing the outputs...? I'm guessing not. 
I'd appreciate some help in trying not to electrocute myself.

EDIT: Turns out that the particular DLM 60-10 power supplies we have do not have a master/slave mode built in

Austin

Comment: I'd ask Sorensen.  You probably can parallel them but power supplies need to be designed with parallel operation in mind.  For a bench power supply such as this I would be surprised if it's not OK but ask otherwise you risk overloading one leading to failure.

Comment: We have DLM power supplies here and have run them this way.  The drawback is that one supply gets all of the load until it reaches its current limit.  If you are doing this in a permanent installation, there is a master/slave mode in the manual that requires use of the remote sense line which splits the load evenly, but is a little more of an effort.

Comment: UPDATE: Looks like this particular unit(s) (DLM 60-10) does not have a master/slave mode. Any other ideas? @JohnBirckhead

Comment: So you're saying that section 2-12 of the manual (Parallel Operation) doesn't apply to your source? That's extremely odd if true. In theory all you need is that source-to-source cable and you're done. Otherwise you can try connecting the remote current monitor from the master to the remote current control of the slave. Do your sources have the analog control headers?

Comment: That is correct @AdamLawrence. When you purchase the DLM supplies, they all come with the same skeleton regardless of which unit you buy. Our units have the SETUP-2_slave switch, but it's not hooked up to anything internally. 
Trying to figure out why the schematic below, by John Birckhead wouldn't work.

Comment: Think I may have figured it out. Although my particular units are a rare case where they don't have master/slave control, I think I can just split the cDAQ command output into two lines. That way I have two masters and I can just splice them into 20A using the schematic below

Comment: Does the power supplies have a constant current limit?

Comment: They units themselves have a limit of 10 A if that is what you are asking @winny

Comment: No. Does it limit to 10 A by foldback, break (fuse emulation) or constant current?

Answer (score -1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVEKJe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You need a couple of 10-amp diodes as shown.  If you use Schottky diodes, you will only lose a half volt or so.

Comment: Incorrect. The supplies won't share current and depending on the load slope and CC turnover point all sorts of strange effects might occur.

Comment: They also won't be 12 V anymore.

Comment: Why not? I'm not sure why this wouldn't work. Can someone explain? I am trying to take the 12 V/ 10 A from each power supply and merge it into 12 V / 20 A.

Comment: Beside a master/slave option, ORing the output via two diodes is a possibility. Best is to use two diodes sharing a common die so they operate at the same temperature and may have close \$V_f\$. As such, a MBR20100 could be an option.